# Cannot push Git to remote repository with http/https

Tags: git, http, https, push

I have a Git repository in a directory served by apache on a server. I have configured WebDAV and it seems to be running correctly. Litmus returns 100% success.

I can clone my repository from a remote host, but when trying to push over http or https, I get the following error:

*error: Cannot access URL
https://git.example.com/repo/, return code 22 fatal: git-http-push failed*

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is highly suggested NOT to use WebDAV if possible. If you must use HTTP/HTTPS then usage of the [git-http-backend](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) CGI script is recommended over WebDAV.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I read an old manual in which there was no mention of git-http-backend. So I gave up with WebDAV and configured this. It's easier, cleaner, and it works!

Answer (score 40):

Edit the following section of your .git/config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
url = http://git.repository.url/repo.git
```

to

```
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
url = http://username:password@git.repository.url/repo.git
```

Then try `git push origin master`.

Edit the authentication details in your config files for other repository URLs as required and push to the required branch.

Comment: Yes just adding the username:password worked for me, and everything else failed.

Comment: My config already had a username. I added a password and now all is good. I've no intention of moving from WebDAV for my tiny project with a repo on a Synology NAS... so this tip was a life saver!

Comment: Thanks! Used this for multiple GitHub accounts on the same local dev machine. No silly SSH multi-identity-config.

Answer (score 3):

As in this [post comment](http://blog.blinker.net/2009/07/21/setting-up-a-git-repository-that-is-accessible-via-http-webdav/#comment-1730), what does your `/Web/git/Logs/ErrorLog` says about that error?

> After looking in `/Web/git/Logs/ErrorLog`, I found out there’s a permission problem on the lock file.
>   In my `httpd-dav.conf`, I have the line…

```
DavLockDB “/usr/var/DavLock”
```

> I then checked the `/usr/` directory, the ‘`var`’ directory was missing.

```
$ mkdir var
$ cd var
$ chown www .
$ chgrp www .
```

> And then repeating the process seems that now I can push!! =)

---

As mentioned by Eddie in the comments and by [Arrowmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227513/arrowmaster) in his (upvoted) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264949/cannot-push-git-to-remote-repository-with-http-https/5265730#5265730), the [smart http protocol](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) is now part of recent Git distribution.
The [`git-http-backend`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) CGI script can takes care of any git commands through http.

[image: smart http]

> The smarter protocols (git and ssh) would instead have a conversation with the git upload-pack process on the server which would determine the exact set of objects the client needs and build a custom packfile with just those objects and stream it over.

---

Git 2.17 (Q2 2018) will add a debugging aid.

See [commit a2b9820](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2b9820ceccf2065a3d3d347e9b1cf7834f5e146) (24 Jan 2018) by [Patryk Obara (`dreamer`)](https://github.com/dreamer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 39a1dd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39a1dd80f8e9542603904bdf2e62d140a88c7e38), 13 Feb 2018)</sup>

> ### `http-push`: improve error log
>
> When `git push` fails due to server-side WebDAV error, it's not easy to
>   point to the main culprit.
>   Additional information about exact `cURL` error and HTTP server response is helpful for debugging purpose.

Comment: I did not find the ErrorLog, but I can say the lock was there and the permissions were good.

Comment: As ArrowMaster pointed out, it is best to move away from DAV which is slower and more prone to update conflicts.  Instead use git-http-backend.cgi, and the appropriate apache ScriptAlias deinitions.

Answer (score 2):

you might need to add the user as a member for the repository and possibly update permissions.

we had to do this with each member that will be contributing on our organizations github repository.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows where my credentials are stored in windows credential manager. I did not want every user to have to edit the config file so I changed the url from http://example.com  to http://git@example.com and it work even though my id is not git. I don't think a user "git" is defined anywhere and assume any name will work. (If you are not on a private network make sure you use https).

Comment: please give example.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in which I was able to clone and pull from the repository using the HTTP protocol, but I was not able to push. I solved this by doing the following.

I changed the url for the remote in the project's .git/config file to match the GitHub SSH url. I then followed all of the instructions at "https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-linux" and troubleshooted with "https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey". The best part is that I did not have deal with Apache or change any HTTP settings on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

En example of write authentified git dav virtualhost with gitweb enable that could solve your problem :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName git.example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/git

        # SSL configuration
        SSLEngine on

        # Fix dav header
        #RequestHeader edit Destination ^https: http: early

        <Directory /var/git>
                DAV on
                Options ExecCgi FollowSymLinks

                # Gitweb config
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
                DirectoryIndex .gitweb.cgi
                SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG /var/git/.gitweb.conf

                # Basic auth config
                AuthType Basic

                # Auth title
                AuthName "Git repositories"

                # Use file and external providers
                AuthBasicProvider file

                # File location
                AuthUserFile /var/git/.htpasswd

                Require method GET OPTIONS PROPFIND
                <LimitExcept GET OPTIONS PROPFIND>
                        Require valid-user
                </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then just clone your repository with your user :

```
git clone https://user@git.example.com/repository
```

And when you will try to push it will ask your password and provide it.

Placing the password in the clone url is a security bad practice as anyone can read it in your .git/config.