# Central git server in a DHCP network

Tags: git, gitolite, dhcp

I have a linux (debian) computer and a mac (10.4) connected through a dhcp router. Now I installed gitolite on the linux box to have a central git repository. My problem now is that I'll always have a different IP when I start the linux computer and I cannot configure the router to give the computers in the network fixed IPs. So my question is: What would be the best way to work with that? Is it possible to define the current linux box IP in /etc/hosts under a domain name? Or should I enter the IPs to push the changes to manually each time? Or do you know any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Note:

You don't have to install Gitolite to have a central repository.
It is only an [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html).

You only need an ssh daemon access or an http server (with the [`git-http-backend` CGI script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265022/6309))  running on your Linux box.
If your Linux box has an hostname, you can use that to reference your linux services (`ssh://` or `http://`)

Comment: Note: some DHCP configuration could be needed: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20090212/register-hostname-dns

Answer (score 0):

What other clients are you accessing the git machine from? With a collection of Linux boxes, you can install Avahi and the mdns hosts lookup method: then referring to `hostname.local` will resolve the hostname by using multicast queries on the local network.

(On Debian, just installing `avahi-daemon` on the server and client machines is sufficient, it contains this magic in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` by default:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you define a static IP on your linux box ?