# Using WebDav with Git - good or bad idea?

Tags: git, unix, ssh, webdav

I'm using a remote server to set up a couple of Git repositories (one per project). I've managed to configure this using WebDav (as our previous SVN installation also used WebDav) over HTTPS. Gettings this to work with the clients was a pain, but seems to be working correctly now.

However, during the troubleshooting the issues we had trying to connect to the server to clone and push etc. we read a few comments here and there that suggested that WebDav combined with Git was discouraged (for example, [Cannot push Git to remote repository with http/https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264949/cannot-push-git-to-remote-repository-with-http-https)).

There doesn't seem to be a very clear argument though, so I'm wondering if it would be worth switching to SSH. The biggest disadvantage of that approach to me would be that we have to create user accounts on the server for each of the users that requires access to the repositorie(s), allowing them to start an SSH session as well (also see http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/). With WebDav this seems much more contained to just the repositories, so for me that feels more 'safe'.

Since I'm not a very experienced sysadmin it could be that there are configuration options I'm unaware of that allow me to contain the user priviliges more when using SSH as well, so please educate me if that is the case.

So the bottom line question is, what are the disadvantages of using WebDav to connect to a remote Git repository and is it worth switching to SSH?

Answer (score 0):

It’s only SVN is built upon WebDav/DeltaV but even there it wasn’t fully implemented.
The Git uses its own protocols so read Git Book to see pros and cons
[Git on the Server - The Protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)
If in short: SSH is fine and much more secure