# On Jenkins only one of two git based job work

Tags: git, jenkins, cloning

I have two jobs on my Jenkins server. Both are based on git but only one works and I don't know why.

### Job 1

The first one works with a Github repository. Configuration is as follows :

> Repository URL: git://github.com/profilsoft/profilsoft.git
>
> Name: origin
>
> Refspec: +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

When I launch a build, I can see that in the log :

> Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Profilsoft - Tools/workspace
>
> Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Profilsoft - Tools/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@14a1e7ad
>
> Using strategy: Default
>
> Last Built Revision: Revision 5441ae757daccf1f3bf2edd392a7131eccdf6184 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
>
> Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Profilsoft - Tools/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@14a1e7ad
>
> Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
>
> Fetching upstream changes from git://github.com/profilsoft/profilsoft.git
>
> Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
>
> Seen branch in repository origin/master
>
> Commencing build of Revision 5441ae757daccf1f3bf2edd392a7131eccdf6184 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
>
> Checking out Revision 5441ae757daccf1f3bf2edd392a7131eccdf6184 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
>
> Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
>
> [workspace] $ ant
>
> Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/lib/tools.jar
>
> Buildfile: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Profilsoft - Tools/workspace/build.xml

The build success without any trouble

### Job 2

The second job have the following configuration

> Repository URL: git@192.168.1.12:front
>
> Name: origin
>
> Refspec: +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

When I launch a build, I can see that in the log :

> Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/profilsoft-wordpress-plugin/workspace
>
> Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/profilsoft-wordpress-plugin/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@72be8e1
>
> Using strategy: Default
>
> Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/profilsoft-wordpress-plugin/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@72be8e1
>
> Cloning the remote Git repository
>
> Cloning repository origin
>
> ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git@192.168.1.12:front
>
> Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: /usr/bin/git clone --progress -o origin git@192.168.1.12:front /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/profilsoft-wordpress-plugin/workspace
>
> Command "/usr/bin/git clone --progress -o origin git@192.168.1.12:front /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/profilsoft-wordpress-plugin/workspace" returned status code 128: Cloning into /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/profilsoft-wordpress-plugin/workspace...
> No protocol specified

### I have tried

1. I put the content of my ~/.shh on /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh with with the correct permissions (600, jenkins:jenkins)
2. I ran the command "/usr/bin/git clone --progress -o origin git@192.168.1.12:front /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/profilsoft-wordpress-plugin/workspace" in the console and it works perfectly (repository is cloned)
3. I have updated the Git Plugin. I have the latest version.
4. A coworker installed Jenkins and he has set the same configuration. The build has succeeded.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I specify that I am logged in as Jenkins and the clone command works fine. But still does not work in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3250131/814304 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248848/814304 .

you can try to add fixed protocol in your settings.