# How to fix bower ECMDERR

Tags: github, bower, yeoman, windows-firewall

I'm using "yeoman" and "bower" on windows 7 but got the following error when I create the app

```
yo webapp
```

The error is

```
bower not-cached    git://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap.git#~3.0.0
bower resolve       git://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap.git#~3.0.0
bower not-cached    git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#~2.6.2
bower resolve       git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#~2.6.2
bower not-cached    git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~1.10.2
bower resolve       git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~1.10.2
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github
.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=No error
```

The version of the yeoman, bower and node

```
c:\yo-test>bower -v
1.2.8

c:\yo-test>yo -version
1.1.2

c:\yo-test>node -v
v0.10.15
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bower install using only https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669091/bower-install-using-only-https)

Answer (score 427, accepted):

In case you might encounter the same issue...It turns out my machine behind firewall, that won't able to access **git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git**

Link: [Unable to Connect to GitHub.com For Cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298986/unable-to-connect-to-github-com-for-cloning)

The solution without changing the firewall:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Credit to @bnguyen82 from [Unable to Connect to GitHub.com For Cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298986/unable-to-connect-to-github-com-for-cloning) and @Sindre Sorhus from [Bower install using only https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669091/bower-install-using-only-https)

Comment: Will this have any other side effects?

Comment: "**Both ssh and https are equivalent**, since Git 1.6.6+ (2010) and the implementation of smart http protocol"  @VonC answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248779/which-is-faster-ssh-or-git-protocol

Comment: I had to define HOME in environment settings and point it to the folder that contained the .gitconfig file.

Comment: (+1), for mentioning link to `bower install question`

Comment: For those who get here because of anjular.js installation problem, that's the solution! thanks!

Comment: Awesome, make my day after a lots of try. finally its work for me. Thankyou :)

Comment: Turned out that one of my entry in bower.json was with `git://`, changed to `https://` - it solved my issue. Thanks for pointing right direction.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem and the answer above didn't work for me. But I found an other one. You can have a problem with your proxy. If you are behind a proxy you have to do theses steps :

put this in [.bowerrc](http://bower.io/docs/config/) to get rid of the err ETIMEDOUT :

```
{
    "directory": "app/bower_components",
    "proxy": "http://PROXYSERVER:PORT",
    "https-proxy": "https://PROXYSERVER:PORT",
    "strict-ssl": false
}
```

And this one to get rid of ECMDERR :

```
git config --global http.proxy http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXYSERVER:PORT
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 10):

Following commands work for me

> npm cache clean
>
> bower cache clean

and then

> bower install

Answer (score 9):

For me [updating git](https://git-scm.com/download/) to the newest version helped.

Answer (score 1):

My bower.json first looked like this:

```
{
  "name": "HelloIonic",
  "private": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.3.1",
    "ion-datetime-picker": "katemihalikova/ionic-datetime-picker#0.4.0",    
    "ion-tree-list": "fer/ion-tree-list#0.0.10"                             
  }
}
```

and I had the "failed to execute git remote -ls" problem. After I changed it to the following it suddenly started working:

```
{
  "name": "HelloIonic",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "^1.3.2",
    "ion-datetime-picker": "^0.4.0",
    "ion-tree-list": "^0.0.10"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "ionic": "^1.0.0-beta.9"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To contribute to [leoh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790275/4597249) (since I don't have enough rep to post a comment):

If, like me, you found that you could not execute the command because git wasn't installed globally on your machine, opening Tools > Options in Visual Studio, then Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools, you will see that, by default, there are two git locations:

- $(DevEnvDir)\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd
- $(DevEnvDir)\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin

By default (for Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise), these respectively map to:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin

Then open a command prompt (Windows + R > "cmd"), navigate to the above locations, and run leoh's command. I wasn't sure which to run it from, so I ran it from both just in case. The issue was resolved for me from then on.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all generators which have and install again. It's will be help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the antivirus' firewall preventing bower to connect with github. I hadn't realized the antivirus was asking through a windows whether i wanted to allow git to perform connection or not.

I allowed it and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

solution provided by Dakkon_jareth works for me, I was not having app/bower_components but library there, I changed that to app/bower_components and started working,
I will also recommend to try 2-3 times after NPM Cache clean.

Comment: If it took 2-3 tries after setting up a proxy, then it probably wasn't the proxy that fixed it. This error can happen if the remote server is unavailable, so you probably just retried until the server was available again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. After installed "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015" this fix it.

Comment: I highly doubt this directly fixed the issue in question. The time it took to install that tool was probably enough for the remote server to start responding to requests again.

Answer (score 0):

I work with VS 2015 and have the NoGit package installed. 
Updated it to the 0.1.0 and it fixed the problem.

Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced some strange behavior with bower failing to install all dependencies.

None of posted solutions worked for me, that's why I'm posting this answer.

In my case bower install **errored** randomly almost each time with different package.
All packages were on github, so why suddenly ?

> unable to resolve github.com

Obviously something was wrong with networking.

Errors were on dockerized **Ubuntu 16.04 running in virtualized rancher**, so a number of possible points of failure were pretty big.

But fortunately the solution was extremely simple.

I realized that this is a basic installation and does not even have basic networking tools.

So after running `apt install net-tools iputils-ping` all errors disappeared forever.

Pretty unexpected for me, hope it helps ...

Answer (score -2):

Instead of struggling with this, just manually download it and then do a `bower install` from local folder instead.