# kraken fails to resolve requirejs

Tags: kraken.js

When running **kraken**, generation works away for a bit and then fails with the error below.
I'm running this on a Windows 7 machine.

The last line of the logs below contains the following error

```
ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jrburke/requirejs-bower.git", exit code of #128
```

But this command works fine when I run that command from the command line.

Anyone any idea of why this could be happening?

Output of the above command that is failing in kraken; but works when run from the command line

```
git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jrburke/requirejs-bower.git
52bffe3a63e290eb7a5f537e55a47b51a9be7763        refs/heads/master
c612f7c20a10a55e2e822fc3b9dd97a5d431a5b0        refs/tags/2.1.0
076edd10a947d4bb4282271129b19726b56d3d5f        refs/tags/2.1.0^{}
bd7a0ccc271fab393de199b837ef1684fd1b7911        refs/tags/2.1.1
97567de20731049599077327d50ea2d25b6b3fba        refs/tags/2.1.1^{}
d0f43bcc160a56757f091cd3e2c6da50e9968958        refs/tags/2.1.10
86a1013946074b057ebfe51158b63474fa8f2288        refs/tags/2.1.10^{}
fc97e49f1ec9fb2f204bef2b60ed21a32d6a2e05        refs/tags/2.1.11
78b2855258a2bb18ee8584fe3cb743f6b94a5bb1        refs/tags/2.1.11^{}
f3406bd98e4e0cb81576953a387d1140ff1aea14        refs/tags/2.1.12
923f4ebdfb3fb2146a06e9e9606bd3ca353d6887        refs/tags/2.1.12^{}
77948b59914d51608fb08afa8a73bacab44ac18b        refs/tags/2.1.13
0417e101d639edb32c4236baad300a5533471640        refs/tags/2.1.13^{}
ebf86ba18b3cc2368c98de3ecd0f8a7056425598        refs/tags/2.1.14
52bffe3a63e290eb7a5f537e55a47b51a9be7763        refs/tags/2.1.14^{}
7f89740b13d736bd06f5b7a739d267d62e579979        refs/tags/2.1.2
83bce385a1e81cfb43935dcfff2bb734a2211df6        refs/tags/2.1.2^{}
d67ed1ecbacdc2045b72c66e03e579fb31763f16        refs/tags/2.1.3
a1788467fc94bf4d92f5126b033e1c0013e9be57        refs/tags/2.1.3^{}
e1bf1c506d441fc0e6c32061cfdf978c94d116c0        refs/tags/2.1.4
d085235ac8dffc2663d8397cb3ba6288bdd4ab22        refs/tags/2.1.4^{}
0541626fe22acecaa9d47c8e0ba0e98d8ccef401        refs/tags/2.1.5
e741a09dd53fc9134e975b5cdf0d9ee6883be565        refs/tags/2.1.5^{}
294681bb28f8876c447022db98c9b8cb82856b83        refs/tags/2.1.6
62a5fa3d34c84ede4f8ad24d99f7daa76233c2ff        refs/tags/2.1.6^{}
367a8d37c8efd8b0fa9b8aa562bd7063701d6806        refs/tags/2.1.7
7b464602ba10ff95d0909f2f406533f458c4c28f        refs/tags/2.1.7^{}
9349562f9efe3e53f1379578358c46d6423bddac        refs/tags/2.1.8
021ff02f1791b6204e62cf0c99ba2531ef423265        refs/tags/2.1.8^{}
d9dbdb06aa65645babe9a1fa6ade702ecf287931        refs/tags/2.1.9
aa1b22e576a0865fb524c11f10ececcaafca39d7        refs/tags/2.1.9^{}
52bffe3a63e290eb7a5f537e55a47b51a9be7763        refs/tags/latest
```

Full output when running kraken, failure on last line.

```
[?] Name: XX
[?] Description: XX
[?] Author: XXX
[?] Template library? Dust
[?] CSS preprocessor library? LESS
[?] JavaScript library? RequireJS
   create .bowerrc
   create .editorconfig
   create .jshintignore
   create .jshintrc
   create .nodemonignore
   create .npmignore
   create Gruntfile.js
   create README.md
   create config\config.json
   create config\development.json
   create index.js
   create package.json
   create public\favicon.ico
   create public\js\.jshintignore
   create public\js\.jshintrc
   create public\js\app.js
   create tasks\clean.js
   create tasks\copyto.js
   create tasks\jshint.js
   create tasks\mochacli.js
   create locales\US\en\errors\404.properties
   create locales\US\en\errors\500.properties
   create locales\US\en\errors\503.properties
   create tasks\i18n.js
   create tasks\localizr.js
   create public\templates\errors\404.dust
   create public\templates\errors\500.dust
   create public\templates\errors\503.dust
   create public\templates\layouts\master.dust
   create tasks\dustjs.js
   create public\css\app.less
   create tasks\less.js
identical public\js\app.js
   create tasks\requirejs.js
bower dustjs-linkedin-helpers#1.1.1       not-cached git://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers.git#1.1.1
bower dustjs-linkedin-helpers#1.1.1          resolve git://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers.git#1.1.1
bower requirejs#2.1.11                    not-cached git://github.com/jrburke/requirejs-bower.git#2.1.11
bower requirejs#2.1.11                       resolve git://github.com/jrburke/requirejs-bower.git#2.1.11
bower dustjs-linkedin#2.0.3               not-cached git://github.com/linkedin/dustjs.git#2.0.3
bower dustjs-linkedin#2.0.3                  resolve git://github.com/linkedin/dustjs.git#2.0.3
bower requirejs#2.1.11                       ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jrburke/requirejs-bower.git", exit code of #128
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Type the following command and try again

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Other guys had a similar problem, see:
[How to fix bower ECMDERR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789683/howto-fix-bower-ecmderr) and [Unable to Connect to GitHub.com For Cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298986/unable-to-connect-to-github-com-for-cloning)

Comment: Apologies I should have mentioned that I had already tried this and that is how I got the command line working. The command line was not working before I used that command.