# Roots.io npm install with fatal error: invalid argument

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, bower

would like to ask around what is the cause that when I try to run
npm install in command prompt and it keeps showing me such error?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\Projects\wordpress\wp-content\themes\roots>npm install

> roots@7.0.3 postinstall C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\Projects\wordpress\wp-content\t
hemes\roots
> node node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && grunt dev

bower not-cached    git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#2.8.2
bower resolve       git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#2.8.2
bower not-cached    git://github.com/scottjehl/Respond.git#1.4.2
bower resolve       git://github.com/scottjehl/Respond.git#1.4.2
bower not-cached    git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.1
bower resolve       git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.1
bower not-cached    git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.1
bower resolve       git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.1
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github
.com/scottjehl/Respond.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: read error: Invalid argument

npm ERR! roots@7.0.3 postinstall: `node node_modules/bower/bin/bower install &&
grunt dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the roots@7.0.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the roots package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && grunt dev
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls roots
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\Projects\wordpress\wp-content\themes\roots
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\Projects\wordpress\wp-content\themes\roots\n
pm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've check with all the folders and ensure necessary permissions is given to all folders and I'm also running command prompt in administrator mode.

Please if anyone can provide me with some assistance. Thank you.

```
Additional system information:
Windows 8.1 Professional x64
Vagrant virtual enviornment v1.7.2
Roots.io v7.0.3-3-g2723692
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to access the uri below?

git://github.com/scottjehl/Respond.git

The error response in your question points to 
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github
.com/scottjehl/Respond.git", exit code of #128

Comment: how do i check if i can access to that uri?

Comment: put in your browser. Actually, please run this command in your command prompt. This will tell if you are able to access the git repo. You should have git installed on your machine to run this.                                          "git clone git://github.com/scottjehl/Respond.git"

Comment: Also check this question which points to similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789683/howto-fix-bower-ecmderr