# ECMDERR during bower install

Tags: angularjs, git, github, bower-install

> I'm new to git, bower and electron etc.

I'm trying to install some dependencies through command line like this

```
bower install angular angular-route angular-material --save
```

It gives me error

[image]

I found  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16301991/2660342)  that says

> You are probably behind a firewall. Try cloning via https – that has a higher chance of not being blocked

Then I tried this

```
bower install https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git
```

but it still giving me error

[image]

Basically Error is

> ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=No such file or directory
>
> Additional error details: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
>   github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=No such file or directory

Can anyone have Idea what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing here? I'm totally stuck over here. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

check this question for more details:
[How to fix bower ECMDERR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789683/how-to-fix-bower-ecmderr)

Comment: still same. Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git/': Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Answer (score 1):

I had some invalid proxy settings in .bowerrc 
Removed them. All good :)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get it to work after i changed my .gitconfig file to sslVerify = false

Here is how my .gitconfig looks like:

```
[http]
        sslVerify = false
[url "https://"]
        insteadOf = git://
[url "https://github.com/"]
        insteadOf = git://github.com/
```