# Differences between git-receive-pack/git-upload-pack and git-http-backend

Tags: git, git-http-backend

To understand more about git, I try to write a very simple Git server using Python and Flask. I registered an endpoint and redirect the calls to [git-http-backend](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend). So far a simple pull works fine. Also simple/small pushes go through.

Now I stumbled over [git-upload-pack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack) and [git-receive-pack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack), and I am wondering why or when I would need them? Are they used by `git-http-backend` in the background? I am not sure if I additionally have to support these commands too.

P.S. I try to wrap my head around SmartHTTP. Does it mean Full-Duplex? Or what is meant to be SmartHTTP vs Dumb? I don't exactly understand what is supposed to be smart if it also just receives and sends/pushes a file?

Comment: This is too broad and vague. The g-h-b docs tell you it invokes upload-pack and receive-pack in response to requests over the wire from git clients, what does "why or when I would need them" refer to? g-h-b implements a command shell, running commands like upload-pack and receive-pack in response to client requests over the [git "smart" http protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

Comment: You don't need anything more from those commands unless you have some need to run them beyond what you can ask g-h-b for. This is Git: basically *anything* you can do with the commands could be legit, the question is "what do you need?".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I presented the [smart http protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248848/6309) in [2011 with Git 1.6.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265022/6309).

But [`git-receive-pack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack) and [`git-upload-pack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack) would be involve even without HTTP, with for instance SSH URL.

I have to know about them because I often install Git on servers where I am not root.
That means the executable `git` is not in `/usr/bin`, but in `/my/path/to/git/usr/bin`

And whenever I do a `git clone` on my PC from that server (or a `git ls-remote`), I get:

```
bash: git-upload-pack: command not found
```

If I try a `git push` from my PC to that server:

```
bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
```

That is because, when you look at the `usr/bin` folder of a Git installation, you would see:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 <auser> <agroup> 3.0M Dec 13  2019 git*
drwxr-xr-x. 5 <auser> <agroup>   45 Jun  8 14:35 ../
drwxr-xr-x. 2 <auser> <agroup>  107 Jun  8 14:35 ./
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 <auser> <agroup>    3 Jun  8 14:35 git-receive-pack -> git*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 <auser> <agroup>    3 Jun  8 14:35 git-upload-pack -> git*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 <auser> <agroup>    3 Jun  8 14:35 git-upload-archive -> git*
```

Meaning [`git-receive-pack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack) and [`git-upload-pack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack) are just symlink to `git` itself(!)

But, because of their naming convention (`git-xxx`), they are actually calling `git` with the command `receive-pack` or `upload-pack`.
(incidently, that works for any script `git-xxx` in your `$PATH`: you can then type `git xxx`, that will call your `git-xxx` script)

For my custom Git installation to work, I had to implement `git-xxx` wrappers:

Example:

```
/my/path/to/git/git-receive-pack:

#!/bin/bash

source "setenv"
"/my/path/to/git/usr/bin/git" receive-pack "$@"
```

With setenv setting the right PATH:

```
export PERLLIB=/my/path/to/git/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl:/my/path/to/git/opt/endpoint/perl-5.22.0/share/perl5/vendor_perl
export PATH=/my/path/to/git/usr/bin:/my/path/to/git/usr/libexec/git-core:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/project/${USER}/refer/pcres/current/usr/lib64
```

And on the client (PC) side, I need, for a remote using the server with custom Git installation, to add:

```
git config --global remote.origin.uploadpack /my/path/to/git/git-upload-pack
git config --global remote.origin.receivepack=/my/path/to/git/git-receive-pack
```

Comment: 50 bounties are actually not enough for this answer! Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed

Comment: It seems I just clicked the bounty, not accepting answer. Fixed and accepted now. Thanks again!